# Prevent CSS changes on "Edit" UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, user-controls, detailsview

I am using User Controls in ASP.NET and C# to develop pages for my project.  With these pages, I have formatted a bunch of CSS into a DetailsView.  However, when I run an "Edit" CommandField, the CSS on the page changes a bunch and I don't know how to stop it (ie. Text all becomes bold, column height changes dramatically, etc.).  I don't want to have to reset these properties every time this button is hit.

Is there anyway to prevent the CSS changes from occurring?

Comment: Is this at runtime, or in the visual studio designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your asp:detailview you can add different cssclasses bound to the type of action in the detailview. You can, for instance, use the `EditRowStyle-CssClass` for when you're editing and use a different class for `InsertRowStyle-CssClass`.